# How to mask input and display the last 4 digit using python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble making this program.
What I need is a program that will ask the user for the number of card, example input is like this:

```
in1 = '1234 4214 1521 5132'
in2 = '52310259 1269102392'
```

The output should be like the following:

```
'xxxx xxxx xxxx 5132'
'xxxxxxxx xxxxxx2392'
```

It should display the last 4 digit of the input. can you guys help me with this program using python.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: as of now i'm still trying to figure out how to make this program work. 
i got a code like this for now
`number = input()
count = len(number) - number.count(' ')
if count == 16 or count == 20:
    for i in range(len(number) - number.count(' ')):`

Comment: Can the spaces occur anywhere in the string (e.g. `'12 34 42 14 15 21 51 32'` or even `'12 3442141521513 2'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def mask(string, digits_to_keep=4, mask_char='x'):

    num_of_digits = sum(map(str.isdigit, string))
    digits_to_mask = num_of_digits - digits_to_keep
    masked_string = re.sub('\d', mask_char, string, digits_to_mask)
    return masked_string
```

This gives:

```
>>> mask(in1)
'xxxx xxxx xxxx 5132'

>>> mask(in1, 6)
'xxxx xxxx xx21 5132'

>>> mask(in2)
'xxxxxxxx xxxxxx2392'
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like this:

```
credit1 = '1234 4214 1521 5132'
credit2 = '52310259 1269102392'

s = credit1[-4:].rjust(len(credit1), '*')
print(s)
s = credit2[-4:].rjust(len(credit2), '*')
print(s)
```

The output you get is:

```
***************5132
***************2392
```

another solution using regex:

```
import re
print(re.sub('\d', '*', credit1[:-4]) + credit1[-4:])
print(re.sub('\d', '*', credit2[:-4]) + credit2[-4:])
```

will keep the spaces, the output is:

```
**** **** **** 5132
******** ******2392
```

**Edit**
A solution for the case where the user wants `k` number of digits to keep:

```
import re
k = 7
c1 = len(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", credit1)) - k
c2 = len(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", credit2)) - k

print(re.sub('\d', '*', credit1, c1))
print(re.sub('\d', '*', credit2, c2))
```

The output for `k=3/4/5/6/7` is:

```
**** **** **** *132
******** *******392

**** **** **** 5132
******** ******2392

**** **** ***1 5132
******** *****02392

**** **** **21 5132
******** ****102392

**** **** *521 5132
******** ***9102392
```

Comment: @DavidS Running `re.sub('\d', '*', credit1[:-6]) + credit1[-6:]` returns `'**** **** ***1 5132'` which reveals only 5 digits.

Comment: @DavidS Note the question asks how to display the last 4 *digits*, not *characters*.

Comment: @EliadL added the option if the user will want to use it

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way. You need to iterate your string from the end in order to find the last four digits and place them in `result` as they are. For the rest of the digits, you can place a `X` mark:

```
def showLastDigits(string, numOfDigits):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(string)-1,-1,-1):
        if string[i] == ' ':
            result.append(string[i])
        elif string[i].isdigit() and counter < numOfDigits:
            result.append(string[i])
            counter += 1
        else:
            result.append('X')
    return "".join(result[::-1])

test1 = "1234 4214 1521 5132"
test2 = "52310259 1269102392"

print(showLastDigits(test1,4))
print(showLastDigits(test2,4))
```

This will return:

```
XXX XXXX XXXX 5132
XXXXXXX XXXXXX2392
```

You can also set the number of digits you want to appear with `numOfDigits` param.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regex like:

```
import re
p= re.compile(r'(\d{4})$')
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/LFlxHM/1)